# Why Java can take multiple parameters but can return only a single object?

Tags: java, history, language-design

Why was java defined such that methods may take as input multiple parameters, 
but may only return a single object (or void)?

Did it make the language somehow easier to implement or use?

Comment: It doesn't really offer any solutions to an efficient way to return multiple arguments either. For the record, if I want a method to be able to return an argument, I pass a cached array (length 1) of the required type as an argument and have it set the first field, alternatively, you could return an object array and use that, but its unnecessary object creation which you want to avoid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because this is the way that C and C++ do it, and the Java language syntax is very similar to (and probably based on) those languages.

In fact, according to [this article](http://sunsite.uakom.sk/sunworldonline/swol-07-1995/swol-07-java.html), Gosling started by extending the C++ compiler, so it makes sense that he would follow much of the same syntax:

> To make development a more platform-neutral process (and thus accommodate the consumer market's demand for CPU flexibility), Gosling began by extending the C++ compiler.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the intention was that multiple return values be encapsulated in an object?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know for sure, but I imagine that Java is executed like any other stack-based runtime.  Which means that passing items as parameters into a method is done easily by simply pushing them onto the stack before transferring control to the method.  Return values are probably handled in the VM like C and C++ do - the return value is always placed in a register, which is by nature single-valued.

It's not a big problem, though, because with generics, returning multiple values can be handled in a type-safe way by returning an instance of something like  `Tuple<type1, type2, type3>`, which isn't too great a burden to bear in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be convention: that's what the major OO languages do/did, so that's what Java did.  However, the official argument would probably be the same as the one about closures - don't include things that will cloud up the standard syntax for mundane tasks with not-really-needed tasks.  Or maybe they figured that a single method should be returning a set of related values that should/could go into an object.  Or maybe they just didn't think of it/have the time (pretty standard developer fare).

On a related note, I found this discussion of using closures to mock multiple returns:
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/brucechapman/archive/2007/11/closures_and_mu.html